# Is it possible to get chatter notifications to my custom native app just like salesforce1

Tags: chatter, salesforcemobilesdk-ios, push-notification

I have a salesforce iOS app that uses the mobile sdk. My users use chatter as a communication mean and they open it through my native app in a safari view controller.

Is there a way to send a notification through my connected app when post, mention, group post etc.. so that my users receive chatter notifications on my native app just like how it works in salesforce1 app.

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has changed since I last looked, there's not way to get access to the push notifications that are generated for the official Salesforce app.

You can however configure your own push notification setup, and send notifications to your app through Apex, it's a bit too involved to put everything here, but it might be provide you with the mechanism you need to send relevant notifications to your users.